# Interaction of weighted averages

Tags: least-squares, interaction, interpretation

I am investigating the effects of tax rates on tax-avoidance by multinationals using OLS-regressions.
The idea is that a multinational will try to move more income to the Bahamas if the tax rates in the other countries it is active in are higher. (see example below)
So, income in the Bahamas is positively affected by the weighted average of foreign taxes.

```
Income=\beta_1*weighted foreign tax rates+\beta*controls+\epsilon
```

However, moving income to the Bahamas is more difficult if the tax authorities are trying to stop you. Therefore, the effect of foreign taxes is lower if the tax authorities audit more frequently. An interaction between foreign taxes and foreign audit probability would capture this.

There are two ways of creating the interaction. You can first create the interaction for each country and then take a weighted average, or take the interaction of the weighted averages.

```
                    Germany     Bahamas    France
 Tax rate             40%          5%        30% 
 Audit probability    10%          0%        15%
 Assets               100k         5k        200k
 Weight               100/305      5/305     200/305


 Bahama's Weighted foreign tax rate    100/305*40+200/305*30=32.79
 Bahama's Weighted foreign audit       100/305*10+200/305*15=13.11

 Interaction option1                   32.79*13.11=429.88
 Interaction option2                   100/305*40*10+200/305*30*15=426.23
```

Option 1 is a 'traditional' interaction. The interpretation and regression equation is easy to set up.

```
Income=\beta_1*weighted tax rates+\beta_2*weighted audit probability+\beta_3*weighted  tax rates*weighted audit probability+\beta*controls+\epsilon
```

Option 2 is a bit different.

```
 Income=\beta_1*weighted tax rates+\beta_2*weighted audit probability+\beta_3*weighted interaction+\beta*controls+\epsilon
```

Contrary to the 'traditional' interaction, I cannot really include the two terms I am interacting separately. Can I interpret the 'weighted interaction' as a normal interaction? Can I omit

```
 \beta_2*weighted audit probability
```

from the above equation, without loss of interpretation?

Comment: Why do you model income as a function of tax rates and the probability of audit? And how would you collect data about tax avoidance?

Comment: The real model has more complexity to it. Using methods set forth by Huizinga in his 2008 paper on tax avoidance. I cut down the issue to the statistical problem, rather than leaving the entire backstory intact. The real model includes a 3 way interaction to adjust for tax avoidance. The third interaction term is included in the 'traditional' way, and doesn't really affect my problem. Therefore, I left it out.

Comment: It's helpful to add relevant information *in the question, not the comments*, including a citation for the paper you mention.